# How do I enable streaming with my react components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components

I have my **CourseChat** component

```
const CourseChat = () => {
  const [socketIOClientId, setSocketIOClientId] = useState('');
  const socket = socketIOClient('https://irisagent.onrender.com');
  const [tokenMessage, setTokenMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);
  ...

    useEffect(() => {
    let tokens: string[] = []; // Temporary variable to store tokens

    if (socketIOClientId == '') {
      socket.on('connect', () => {
        setSocketIOClientId(socket.id);
        console.log('connected');
      });
    }

    socket.on('start', () => {
      console.log('start');
      tokens = []; // Reset tokens when socket starts
    });

    socket.on('token', (token) => {
      console.log(token); //logs each token
      tokens.push(token); // Add token to tokens array
      setTokenMessage(tokens); // Set tokens to state
    });

    socket.on('end', () => {
      console.log('end');
      setTokenMessage([]); // Set tokens to state
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [user]);

 ...

  <MessageList
    messages={messages.map(mapChatMessageToMessage)}
    loading={loading}
    messageListRef={messageListRef}
    userImage={user?.picture || ''}
    userName={user?.name || ''}
    tokenMessage={tokenMessage}
   />

  ...
```

within the **MessageList** component I have:

```
function MessageList({
  messages,
  loading,
  messageListRef,
  userImage,
  userName,
  tokenMessage,
}: MessageListProps) {
  return (

...

{loading && tokenMessage && (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-32 w-full bg-white via-gray-900/70 to-gray-800/30">
          <div className="flex-shrink-0 p-1">
            <div className="w-full text-gray-300 p-2 sm:p-4 overflow-wrap break-words">
              <span className="mt-2 inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2 py-1 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium ring-1 ring-inset bg-purple-400/10 text-custom-purple ring-custom-purple-light">
                <img
                  src="/images/iris.png"
                  alt="Iris logo"
                  className="h-5 w-auto"
                />
              </span>
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-full">
                  {tokenMessage.map((message, index) => (
                    <ReactMarkdown
                      key={index}
                      linkTarget="_blank"
                      className="markdown text-xs text-black sm:text-sm md:text-base leading-relaxed"
                      remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
                    >
                      {message}
                    </ReactMarkdown>
                  ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
```

This currently isn't working. Loading turns true soon as the socket is started. I want the loading section to display the tokenMessage as it changes word by word. Currently it is updating once, then goings away when loading is false. Thank you!